# Multiplying a floor function

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, ceiling-and-floor-functions, least-common-multiple

b and y are integers. Is it valid to multiply like this?

$ \left  \lfloor \frac{lcm(b,y)}{b} \right \rfloor * gcd(b,y)  = \left  \lfloor \frac{by}{b} \right \rfloor = y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the least common multiple of $b$ and $y$ *is* a multiple of $b$, so your first fraction is an integer, and the floor function does nothing:

$$\left\lfloor\frac{\operatorname{lcm}(b,y)}b\right\rfloor=\frac{\operatorname{lcm}(b,y)}b\;.$$

Thus, you’re really just calculating

$$\frac{\operatorname{lcm}(b,y)}b\cdot\gcd(b,y)=\frac{by}b=y\;.$$